# Proof of the Probability of Union of 3 Sets is Disjoint

Tags: probability-theory

I need help with the mathematical proof of:

**If P($A \cup B \cup C$) = 1, then the events A,B,and C are disjoint (mutually exclusive).**

I started with:

P($A \cup B \cup C$) + P($A \cup B \cup C)^c$ = 1 . Which means that P($A \cup B \cup C)^c$ must be 0...

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It,s not true.

**Conterexample (dice with three sides).** Let $\Omega = \left \{ a,b,c \right\}$, $P(\left\{ a \right\}) = P(\left\{ b \right\}) = P(\left\{ c \right\}) = \frac{1}{3}$, $A = \left \{ a,b\right\}$, $B = \left\{ b,c \right\}$, $C = \left \{ a,c \right\}$. Then
$$ P(A\cup B \cup C) = 1, \text{ but } P(A \cap B) = P(B\cap C) = P(A\cap C) = \frac{1}{3}.$$